# Purescript: Could not match type

Tags: purescript

In the REPL this works:

```
> mm n = (\n -> n * 2) <$> n
> mm (2:3:Nil)
(4 : 6 : Nil)
```

in a file this compiles and I can run it:

```
squareOf ls =
  map (\n -> n * n)  ls
```

however when I add a type definition to that function

```
squareOf :: List Int -> Int
squareOf ls =
  map (\n -> n * n)  ls
```

I get an error:

```
 Could not match type

    List Int

  with type

    Int


while checking that type t0 t1
  is at least as general as type Int
while checking that expression (map (\n ->
                                       (...) n
                                    )
                               )
                               ls
  has type Int
in value declaration squareOf

where t0 is an unknown type
      t1 is an unknown type
```

I tried changing the signature to a type alias of the list, and also I tried a forall definition with no luck.
If I inspect the definition created when I don't put signatures in my function I get:

```
forall t2 t3. Functor t2 => Semiring t3 => t2 t3 -> t2 t3
```

Can anyone explain why my signature is incorrect and also why am I getting this signature for the function?

Cheers

Edit: Thanks for the comments, updating the fn definition so it returns a `List Int` as well, and , of course it solves the problem

Comment: Check the return type of your function: `Int`. But map is structure preserving, so it must return a `List` of something in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're repl function is the behaviour you're after, you've missed out the map operator (`<$>`) in your later definitions.

Your repl function (with variables renamed for clarity) has the type:

```
mm :: forall f. Functor f => f Int -> f Int
mm ns = (\n -> n * 2) <$> ns
```

Which is to say: *mm maps "times two" to something that is mappable"* (i.e. a Functor)

Aside: you could be more concise/clear in your definition here:

```
mm :: forall f. Functor f => f Int -> f Int
mm = map (_*2)
```

This is similar to your `squareOf` definition, only now you're *squaring* so your use of `(*)` is more general:

```
squareOf :: forall f. Functor f => Semiring n => f n -> f n
squareOf = map \n -> n * n
```

Because `(*)` is a member of the Semiring typeclass.

But the signature you gave it suggests you're after some kind of `fold`? Let me know what output you expect from your `squareOf` function and I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is `map`:

```
class Functor f where
  map :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Narrowing to `List Int` and `Int -> Int`, the compiler infers

```
map :: (Int -> Int) -> List Int -> List Int
```

So, in `squareOf`, the expression reduces to a list of integers, not an integer. That is why the compiler complains.